# How to install a provisioning profile on windows 7 for testing

Tags: iphone, testing, windows-7, provisioning

how can I install a provisioning profile on windows 7?
Just dragging it onto the iTunes icon doesn't seem to work like it would on a mac...
It only "pins" it together.

Answer (score 1):

Try dragging it into the list of applications.